# Solidity YUL-Inline-assembly revert with custom error

Tags: solidity

Hello im trying to revert a custom error in YUL inline-assembly

```
function mint(uint256 amountToMint) external onlyOwner() {
    assembly {
      // check if exceed maxSupply
      let maxSupplySlot := sload(maxSupply.slot)
      let res := lt(add(amountToMint, mload(counter.slot)), add(maxSupplySlot, 1))
      let ptrError := mload(0x40)
      mstore(ptrError, 14)
      mstore(add(ptrError, 0x20), 0x4d6178537570706c795265616368) // => "MaxSupplyReach"
      if iszero(res) { revert(ptrError, 0x40) }

      // populate mapping balanceOf
      let ptr := mload(0x40)
      mstore(ptr, caller())
      mstore(add(ptr, 0x20), balanceOf.slot)
      let slot := keccak256(ptr, 0x40)
      sstore(slot, amountToMint)

      // increment counter
      let counterSlot := sload(counter.slot)
      let resCounter := add(counterSlot, amountToMint)
      sstore(counter.slot, resCounter)
    }
  }
```

dont know if i do it correctly my output is like that.

```
0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000e0000000000000000000000000000000000004d6178537570706c795265616368
```

[my foundry error when i revert with `revert(0,0)` it pass but dont pass with custom error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRg0H.png)

thank's for ur help :)

Answer (score 0):

not sure if you have noticed, but your result is actually what you wanted. It is a hex string, which converted to ASCII yields:

`0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000e0000000000000000000000000000000000004d6178537570706c795265616368`

`14MaxSupplyReach`

with 14 being the string length you stored.